# Sleep() vs sleep_for()

Tags: c++, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

Can someone explain the difference in behavior between these two ways of stopping a thread and then continue it again?.

```
Sleep(); //from Win32

std::this_thread::sleep_for();
```

I remark in **terms of multithreading behavior** not in systems compatibility.

Comment: You mean `sleep()` in `unistd.h`?

Comment: Or Win32 [`Sleep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: [`Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) has this caveat: *A value of zero causes the thread to relinquish the remainder of its time slice to any other thread that is ready to run. If there are no other threads ready to run, the function returns immediately, and the thread continues execution.*  Also `Sleep` only takes millis whereas `sleep_for` can take any duration.

Comment: Sleep is a windows api function. sleep_for is a c++ standard function. sleep_for, on windows, is probably implemented with Sleep or another equivalent.

Comment: I mean Win32 Sleep().

Comment: My slightly flippant answer would be, the difference is: “error: 'Sleep' was not declared in this scope”, or, alternatively: “fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory”.

Comment: Do you want someone to read [the documentation on `Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx) and [the documentation on `std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) and put the differences into a nice list so you can save time reading?

Comment: Pretty safe to assume that sleep_for() calls the OS function.  So no difference.  Sleeping a thread is gauche.

Comment: @nwp Yes, that would be a good answer.

Comment: In terms of multithreading behavior: `Sleep` behaves exactly as documented in the Microsoft documentation. The exact behaviour of `std::this_thread::sleep_for();` is implementation dependent, it _may_ just end up calling `Sleep` or it may do it otherways. Anyway it is conformant to [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for). Check the source code if you want to know for sure what is going on under the hood.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in how they behave.  Portability though is a different aspect.  `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` should compile on any C++11 compiler.  `Sleep()` will only compile on windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is that `sleep_for()` is defined by the C++11 standard, and `Sleep()` is defined by the Windows API. If you use `sleep_for()`, it is quite likely, though not certain, that the compiler will generate code that calls `Sleep()` when compiling for Windows. However, since it is a C++11 standard function, that means that any compiler (correctly) implementing the C++11 standard will have some way to generate code for the functionality described by the [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) for any platforms it supports.

The other major difference is that `sleep_for()` takes an `std::chrono::duration` as a parameter instead of an integer in milliseconds. This allows you to more easily and more precisely specify the time for which you want the thread to sleep. It also moves some documentation information into the type system.

You wanted to know the implications of `sleep_for()` versus `Sleep()` for multithreading, and all I can say is that `sleep_for()` has the implications defined in the C++11 standard, and `Sleep()`, has the implications defined in the Windows API. And if you check the reference, each one talks about *its* respective thread type. So if you're using C++11 threads, use `sleep_for()`. If you're using Win32 threads directly, use `Sleep()`. `Sleep()` does not have any notion of C++11 threads, and so does not have clearly defined behavior. Likewise, `sleep_for()` does not have a notion of Windows API threads, and so does not have clearly defined behavior there either. The documentation for each function specifies its interactions with its respective threads. Don't mix standards.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but a side benefit of using `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` is the inherent readability of the argument. e.g sleep_for(std::chrono::hours(1)) vs sleep(3600).

Comment: @user3224083 You can use [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) in C++ to make them even more readable e.g. `this_thread::sleep_for(1h)` or `this_thread::sleep_for(500ms)` or `this_thread::sleep_for(10s)`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Literals for more information

Answer (score 0):

While you call a sleep method like below it instructs the O/S to suspend the thread for that specific time slice provided as parameter to sleep() function/method. Once this function execute O/S temporarily stop that thread and put on sleep mood. By doing that O/S also release the micro processor from it(from the sleeping thread) so that processor can be assign to another thread or process which is waiting for a processor time. There is no any major difference between the two. `Sleep()` is for windows and you have to add windows header file `<windows>` and next one, you can use in both windows and Unix environment and need to use header file `<chrono>`.

```
 Sleep(); //from Win32
 std::this_thread::sleep_for();
```

You can use both the sleep function like below:-

```
 Sleep(100); //sleep for 100 m/s but only in windows    
 std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));//sleep for 100 m/s. Can be use in both windows and Unix environment
```

After 100 m/s O/S will wake up the sleeping thread and reassign the processor to it for further execution and operation.